# Help in identifying two parts

Tags: switches, components, converter, circuit-protection, ac-dc

I need to identify two parts that I need to replace, but I'm having a hard time doing it.

These are the parts:

Part 1:
[image]
From my research I think it is a trigger switch (http://www.jiaben.com/en/pro.asp?BID=45&SID=30), but I don't know where to find one to replace it or how should I search for a replacement.

Part 2:
[image]
[image]

I think it is a 250Vac to 50Vdc converter, but I can't find one the internet anything resembling it.

Any help?

Comment: Do not post links to images. Post the images themselves. I'm not going to go click on a link just to look at a picture

Comment: @DerStrom8 thanks for the warning, edited

Comment: First one is a DPDT switch, second looks like a circuit breaker or something along those lines.

Comment: @brhans good point - deleted !

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the images, downvote removed =)